# Weak linkage with inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, elf, inline-assembly

I'm trying to use `weak` symbol attributes of `ELF` format with inline assembly. When I try to use `.weak` assembly directive, assembly output contains both `.weak` and `.global` directives.

**foo.c**

```
__asm(".weak foo");
void foo(void)
{
    /* EMPTY FUNCTION! */
}
```

**foo.s**

```
#APP
    .weak foo
#NO_APP
    .global foo
```

The code is working fine; but in this case, when the linker sees the symbol both global and weak, could it cause any problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use inline asm to try to work around the compiler, use `__attribute__((weak))` to have the compiler emit `.weak` itself.  [gcc function attributes in the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)

```
__attribute__((weak))
void foo(void){
}
```

[Compiled on the Godbolt compiler explorer with gcc and clang](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'__attribute__((weak))%0Avoid+foo(void)%0A%7B%0A++++/*+EMPTY+FUNCTION!!+*/%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.10452961672473,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'1',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:48,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'1',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),l:'4',m:52,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:49.89547038327527,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
    .text
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .file   "example.cpp"
    .weak   foo()                 # -- Begin function foo()
    .p2align        4, 0x90
    .type   foo(),@function
foo():                                # @foo()
.Lfunc_begin0:
        ret
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   foo(), .Lfunc_end0-foo()
```

Comment: I know `__attribute__` or `_Pragma` could be a better solutions; but I still wonder if it is problematic to contains both `.weak` and `.global` for a symbol.

Comment: @kurtfu: I'm not sure.  But there's no guarantee that the compiler won't reorder stuff at global scope.  I guess `.weak foo` doesn't have to be right before the label, though, so that's ok.  And for C++ you'd have to manually mangle the name yourself.  (And on some platforms you'd have to use `.weak _foo` vs. `.weak foo` on ELF/Linux.  Not sure if any of those platforms (e.g. OS X) have weak symbols.)  Anyway, point is that the attribute is at least as portable as GNU C inline-asm syntax using GAS directives.